# Como importar registro de só uma coluna CSV dentro de uma coluna Sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Eu tenho um arquivo em csv com várias colunas **"ID,NOME_RUA,DATA"** e quero inserir o registro de uma coluna **"NOME_RUA"** que está dentro do arquivo csv na minha tabela sql server chamada "DADOS". A minha tabela "DADOS" no Sql server possui várias colunas **"ID,NOME_RUA,DESTINO"** no entanto, só preciso do registro "NOME_RUA" que está no meu csv para inseri-lo dentro de uma coluna "NOME_RUA" da tabela "DADOS" do sql server.
Alguém sabe como resolver isso? só sei que vou ter que usar um **join** para especificar cada registro da TABELA "DADOS"

TABELA DADOS TEM COMO COLUNA:

```
-ID
-NOME_RUA
-DATA
```

O ARQUIVO CSV TEM COMO COLUNA:

```
-ID
-NOME_RUA
-DESTINO
```

Comment: Utilize Openrowset para abrir o arquivo CSV como se fosse uma tabela. Desta forma você pode utilizar o JOIN. Mas é preferível importar o arquivo CSV para uma tabela temporária, realizar as devidas validações e somente após efetuar o JOIN entre a tabela DADOS e a tabela temporária. Ao final, apagar a tabela temporária.

Comment: @JoséDiz valeu cara. isso tbm pode ajudar sim. quis ir de uma forma mais difícil. Esse jeito seu simplifica as coisas. Valeu

Comment: @JoséDiz Não vai querer compor uma resposta utilizando o `OPENROWSET`. Só falta incluir uns códigos de exemplo neste seu passo-a-passo. :)